# How to turn of automatic quote insertion

Tags: android-studio

When typing a resource, Android Studio inserts two quotes after I type `=`, and puts the cursor in between. So when I type the quote, the cursor is in the wrong position and I end up with an error in the file. I'll type what I want to type, I'll type a quote myself, so I'd very much like to turn off quote insertion. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> SmartKeys -> Add quotes for attribute value on typing '=' and attribute compeletion (set **true**)

Comment: I did find it in the mean time, but I'll still give you the accepted answer :-)